# attribute error : image instance has no attribute 'detectFaces'

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

```
from imgproc import *

cam = Camera(160, 120)
view = Viewer(cam.width, cam.height, "Face detection")

while True:
    image = cam.grabImage()

    faces = image.detectFaces()

    for face in faces:
        # extract the x, y, width and height from the tuple
        x, y, width, height = face

        # use this information to draw an orange rectangle around the face
        image.drawRect(x, y, width, height, 128, 0, 255)

    view.displayImage(image)
```

Comment: Which version of `imgproc` are you using? Maybe updating it will fix the problem.